# cubegeometry diagonal issue in three js

Tags: opengl-es, three.js, webgl

I need to create CubeGeometry with wireframe but without diagonals, I used BoxHelper but I cannot color cube. Can any one suggest me how to color cube using BoxHelper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several options. Here are the patterns to follow:

```
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.BoxGeometry( 10, 10, 10 ), new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial() );
//scene.add( mesh ); // optional

var helper = new THREE.BoxHelper( mesh );
helper.material.color.set( 0x00ffff );
scene.add( helper );

// alternate method
var helper = new THREE.EdgesHelper( mesh, 0xff0000 );
scene.add( helper );
```

Here is a fiddle to help you: http://jsfiddle.net/Lv2jseLb/

[image]

note: `CubeGeometry` has been renamed to `BoxGeometry`.

three.js r.84

Comment: Thank you for reply but as I already mentioned I used this boxhelper it's good, but I cant give a color to BoxHelper rather than borders to BoxHelper which is defined by(helper.material.color.set()). Can i give color to BoxHlper also

Comment: `BoxHelper` and `EdgesHelper` are lines. Can you add the cube to the scene AND the helper to the scene?

Comment: sorry for replying late , Yes but i cant see lines that is generated by boxhelper, cube color is overriding boxhelper lines.

Comment: For the cube material add these properties: `polygonOffset: true, polygonOffsetFactor: 1, polygonOffsetUnits: 1`. You can also increase the line width of the helper: `helper.material.linewidth = 3`, unless you are running MS Windows.

Comment: I added above properties to MeshPhongMaterial, and also i tried with MeshBasicMaterial but no luck, it is overriding cube color to boxhelper, I added transparent to true and opacity to 0.1 to the material, its working but i can see cube is not that good...

Comment: The title of your post is about not showing the diagonal. Please do not add additional conditions to to your question after it has been answered. Please accept this answer by clicking on the checkmark, and make a new post detailing your additional constraints. Thank you.

Comment: If you know English then  I think you can understand this (I need to create CubeGeometry with wireframe but without diagonals, I used BoxHelper but I cannot color cube. Can any one suggest me how to color cube using BoxHelper.)

Comment: Just a friendly note that the point light doesnt seem to work here? What API changed?

Comment: @StevenLu Thanks for the tip. The pattern `light.position = camera.position` is [no longer valid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26905929/three-js-2xmeshes-using-same-vector-as-position/26916159#26916159). In this case, the workaround was to add the point light as a child of the camera.