# THREE.js : 2xMeshes using same vector as position

Tags: javascript, three.js

Just did an update from r67 - r69 in ThreeJS and ends up having problems referring their positions to one (same) vector.

Before I did this which worked:

```
var vector = new THREE.Vector3(50, 50, 50);
_Mesh1.position = vector;
_Mesh2.position = vector;
```

which made it possible that when I moved one of the meshes it moved the other one as well.

In r69 the position vector remains the same (aka 0, 0, 0) which means that I have to manually set the X, Y and Z coords for each mesh whenever I mode another one.

Am I missing some change here? Or what should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Object3D`'s `position`, `rotation`, `quaternion` and `scale` properties are now immutable.

See the source code file `Object3D.js`.

You can no longer use the following pattern:

```
object.position = vector;
```

Instead, you must use either

```
object.position.set( x, y, z );
```

or

```
object.position.copy( vector );
```

three.js r.69

Comment: Is there any technical reason why it's not possible to, for example, specify that a specific `Vector3` instance should be used for the `position` during the construction of an `Object3D`?