# ThreeJS r69 Trackball controls, camera and directional Light

Tags: javascript, graphics, 3d, three.js, perspectivecamera

I need to sync trackball controls and camera with the directional light.

My case scenario:
Init an empty scene with camera, lights and controls.
Load a bufferGeometry obj, get its centroid and set camera and controls position and target relative to the obj centroid.
Basically I simply set camera position and controls.target with:

```
camera.lookAt( position );
camera.position = position;
controls.target.copy( position );
```

where position is a Three.Vector3 obj.

Directional light has to sync automatically with controls.

I did it using threejs r66:

```
function init(){
...
directionalLight.position = controls.object.position;
directionalLight.target.position = controls.target;
...
}
```

where controls is a THREE.TrackballControls object.

With threejs r69 does not work anymore.
Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Simone

---

Solved using a pointLight instead a directionalLight.

var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 1, 100 );
camera.add( pointLight );

Thanks all for the help

Comment: How does it 'not work'? Do you get an error? Which aspect doesn't work?

Comment: The light does not follow the camera movement while interacting with trackball controls. Thus, directionalLight.target.position is not the same compared to controls.target (this one changes every translation/rotation etc )

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26905929/three-js-2xmeshes-using-same-vector-as-position/26916159#26916159

Comment: If it is immutable, how can I sync the light with trackball controls? If I move the camera, the directionalLight.target.position has to follow TrackballControls.target

Comment: directionalLight.position.set(controls.object.position.x,controls.object.position.y,controls.object.position.z);

Comment: or you can set lookpoint = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0); and set controls.target = lookpoint ; when you move controls lookpoint is changed to. To animate() you can add light.target.position.set(lookpoint .x, lookpoint .y, lookpoint .z); and light will always put light on your controls target (point which your camera is orbiting)...

Comment: I would not use a directioal light for this purpose. I would use a point light instead -- like so: `scene.add( camera ); camera.add( pointLight ).`

Comment: Thank you all for the help. I choose to use a pointLight and add it to the camera. Perfect.

Answer (score 0):

The solution ( thanks to WestLangley ) is:

```
var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 1, 100 ); 
camera.add( pointLight );
```