# THREE.js Migration r60 to r70: now cannot write: mesh.position = myVector3()

Tags: three.js, position, migration, mesh

I am migrating a THREE.js app from r60 to r70.  Amongst other changes I notice that r60 constructs of the following form no longer work in r70.

```
mesh.position.set(0,0,0);
myVector3 = new THREE.Vector3 (100,200,300);
mesh.position = myVector3;
```

This applies to meshes, pointLights, presumably to all Object3D's but I havent tested further.

In the above example the  `mesh.position` x,y,z values remain unchanged at (0,0,0).  For illustration see [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6papp6mf/5/) and compare lines 70 and 73.

```
    //...The next line DOES NOT update Sphere_mesh.position.x
    Sphere_mesh.position = NewPos_vector3;//...

    //...The next line DOES update Sphere_mesh.position.x
    Sphere_mesh.position.x = NewPos_vector3.x
```

In a debugger no console warning is given during execution that the assignment has not worked.  In the very brief [THREE.js migration notes for (r68 --> r69)](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration) I see something about an Object3D's position no longer being immutable but I don't know what that means.

Anyway, **my question**

Is there a standard THREE construct or function  I can use to copy x,y,z values from a Vector3 object to the x,y,z values of a mesh.position rather than the effective, but verbose, form such as

```
mesh.position.x = myVector3.x;
mesh.position.y = myVector3.y;
mesh.position.z = myVector3.z; ?
```

e.g. something such as

```
mesh.position = F_Get_Object3DPosition_from_Vector3(myVector3);   ?
```

I know it would be easy to write my own function but a standard THREE function would be more likely to evolve smoothly with future versions of THREE.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26905929/three-js-2xmeshes-using-same-vector-as-position/26916159#26916159

Comment: Ah thanks. I did search quite hard through other questions but missed that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

position beeing immutable means that the position property can not be changed.

so

```
mesh.position = anything;
```

won't work (but you already discovered this)

what you can do is not change the position, but you have to change position values.

in your case, the easiest way is

```
mesh.position.copy (myVector3);
```

Comment: Thanks.  The ".copy" method is exactly what I wanted although  IMO it would be more intuitive if the name was ".copyValues".

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant myVector3 not myVector3() in the last line... Anyway, I though that would work too but the thing is, you are applying a Vector to something that supposed to be a point/Vertex. Even if that worked in my opinion it wasn't the right way to do it. How about using a simple array:

```
mesh.position.set(0,0,0);
new_position = [100,200,300]
mesh.position.fromArray(new_position,0)
```

in which 0 is the starting index. So you can have multiple position sets in one array

Comment: Yes thanks you are right it should be vector3 in the third line of code.  I wasnt previously aware of .fromArray method. Interesting.   Actually I see that Object3d.position is a Vector3 object (according to documentation at http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/Object3D). In my case I already store points as Vector3 objects so the .fromArray approach would not suit in this case.