# Three.js Object3d position not being set

Tags: javascript, three.js

This should be really, really simple - but it's wrecking my head by not working.

```
console.log(this.cameraTarget.position); // THREE.Vector3 {x: 374, y: 0, z: -186, constructor: function, set: function…}

var targetSphere = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(10, 100, 100), new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial());

targetSphere.position = this.cameraTarget.position;

console.log(targetSphere.position); // THREE.Vector3 {x: 0, y: 0, z: 0, constructor: function, set: function…}
```

So this.cameraTarget is an object (not an Object3D) that has a position property which is a Vector3.  When I assign that to the position property of a Mesh, it gets ignored.  Totally.  Any ideas?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26905929/three-js-2xmeshes-using-same-vector-as-position/26916159#26916159.