# Tween.js rotation not working when using Three.js loader

Tags: javascript, three.js, tween

I am working on a simulation project that was started a few years ago. They were using older versions of three.js and tween.js libs and I had to upgrade them for other reasons. I have a problem that piece of code that used to work, now doesn't and I can't figure out why...

Now, let me explain what is the problem. At the start of the app, meshes are loaded by calling this function for each mesh:

```
function loadMesh(objPath, objName, worldScene, initPosition) {
    if (initPosition == undefined) {
        initPosition = new THREE.Vector3();
    }
    var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    loader.load(objPath, function (geometry, materials) {
        for (var material in materials) {
            materials[material].shading = THREE.FlatShading;
        }
        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));
        mesh.scale.set(1, 1, 1);
        mesh.name = objName;
        mesh.position = initPosition;
        mesh.positionO = initPosition.clone();

        worldScene.add(mesh);
        objects.push(mesh);
        objDict[objName] = mesh;
        loadCounter--;
    });
}
```

NOTE: I will just show animation creation, I call "start" method on them later, of course
Now, it works when I try to move that object by changing its **position** with something like this:

```
new TWEEN.Tween(objDict["Screws"].position)
    .to({y: 5}, 1000)
    .delay(500);
```

but if I try to **rotate** my object like this, it doesn't work:

```
new TWEEN.Tween(objDict["ms_LidUpper"].rotation)
    .to({x: -1.571}, 1000)
    .delay(500);
```

I tried to solve this, but couldn't find anything... Note that this code worked before! I think the problem is JSONLoader because when I run the code in debug mode, **mesh** object was missing **matrixRotationWorld** atribute and had **matrixWorldNeedsUpdate** attribute on false, and in the previos app version **matrixWorldNeedsUpdate** was true and there was **matrixRotationWorld** atribute.

Any help will be greatly appriciated!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26905929/three-js-2xmeshes-using-same-vector-as-position/26916159#26916159

Comment: @WestLangley Hey, but **.position** works... this can't be that problem

Comment: @WestLangley hey, sorry, man, it was something similar to what you said in the end... thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Use tween like this way

```
var coords = { x: 0, y: 0 };
new TWEEN.Tween(mesh.rotation).to({x: 10, y: 10}, 3000).onUpdate(function () {
    mesh.rotation.x = coords.x;
    mesh.rotation.y = coords.y;
}).start();
```

Comment: Don't you mean:

new TWEEN.Tween(coords ).to({x: 10, y: 10}, 3000).onUpdate(function () {