# Rotation does not change after setting transformation matrix for camera

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

Any idea how to apply transformation matrix to PerspectiveCamera?
I have a transformation matrix and I am setting it to Perspective camera by using

```
camera.applyMatrix(transformationMatrix);
```

It correctly sets `camera.position` but `camera.quaternion` remains unchanged. Rotation works only when I set `camera.matrixAutoUpdate = false` but it breaks trackballcontrols. I have also tried adding `camera.updateMatrix` to trackballcontrols but that again, resets rotation.
 I have tried setting up position, quaternion and scale of camera manually as:

```
camera.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
camera.useQuaternion = true;

var position = new THREE.Vector3();
var quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();
var scale = new THREE.Vector3(1, 1, 1);
transformationMatrix.decompose(position, quaternion, scale);

camera.position.copy(position);
camera.quaternion.coy(quaternion);
camera.scale.copy(scale);

camera.updateMatrix();
```

It yields the same result, everything is set correctly but trackballcontrols does not work.

**Edit:** I want to set the matrix once, not at every frame.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26905929/three-js-2xmeshes-using-same-vector-as-position/26916159#26916159) and update your question.

Answer (score 0):

Inside animate loop try to call `camera.matrix.identity()` before `camera.applyMatrix(transformationMatrix)` and call `controls.update()` after `camera.applyMatrix(transformationMatrix)`:

http://jsfiddle.net/95u904m7/1/

Comment: Here you are applying matrix at every call of ``animate`` but that not what I am doing, I am applying the matrix in ``init`` once.