# Can't copy a THREE.Vector3

Tags: javascript, inheritance, three.js

I think my problem is more a javascript inheritance problem than a Three.js one.

I am not very familiar with inheritance in javascript, so after a few tutorial, I came up with [this snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/dr38tyq6/2/) and I can't figure out why it doesn't do what I expect.

```
var MyClass = function() {

    THREE.PerspectiveCamera.apply(this, arguments);   

    // Here this.position is default value, (0,0,0)

    this.position = new THREE.Vector3(1,2,3);

    // this.position is unchanged, like if 
    // the previous affectation didn't do anything

}

MyClass.prototype = Object.create(THREE.PerspectiveCamera.prototype);
MyClass.prototype.constructor = MyClass;

var obj = new MyClass();
```

This does what I expect it to do if I remove the inheritance, and I can't reproduce this with stuff other than Three.js objects.

There is probably something I'm missing, but I can't see what.

Do you have an idea ?

Thank you !

Comment: This is your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26905929/three-js-2xmeshes-using-same-vector-as-position/26916159#26916159

Comment: Arf, I knew I should've look better... thank you ! But then... my problem has no link with inheritance, does it ? Since it's the immutability of `this.position`... maybe you should give an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot assign an object's position a new `THREE.Vector3`, as you are doing:

```
this.position = new THREE.Vector3( 1, 2, 3 );
```

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26905929/three-js-2xmeshes-using-same-vector-as-position/26916159#26916159), Object3D's `position`, `rotation`, `quaternion` and `scale` properties are immutable. Use the `set()` method, instead.

```
this.position.set( 1, 2, 3 );
```

three.js r.71

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for the duplicate

Answer (score 4):

The way inheritance is supported in javascript is really complex and if you don't want to write code you and your mates can't read after a few months then you should think about another way to solve your problem.

I think of a wrapper constructor around THREE.PerspectiveCamera.prototype:

```
var MyClass = function () {
    this.perspectiveCamera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(arguments);
    this.perspectiveCamera.position = new THREE.Vector3(1, 2, 3);
}

var instance = new MyClass();
```

This should do the trick.

But if you are interested in the prototype concept, here are a few good to knows:

- passing an instance of a structure to a prototype means, that all instances of this prototype will reference to the same instance of the structure
- you should never set an prototype to an instance of another prototype, because this will eventually include some structures (see above)
- the best way is to iterate through all members of the old prototype (recursivly) and clone them to the new prototype.

some links for further knowledge:

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/javascript_pass

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript