# Threejs, CSS3Renderer, mixed renderer sizing and panning issue

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, three.js

This issue is happening in Chrome only.

**Here's what I have tried:**

I am using the webGL renderer to place a plane geometry in the 3d environment using threejs. This code runs inside a class with the scene as a member of the class:

```
var planeMaterial   = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x000000, transparent:true, opacity:0.5, side: THREE.DoubleSide });
var planeWidth = 1080;
var planeHeight = planeWidth;
var planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( planeWidth, planeHeight );
var planeMesh = new THREE.Mesh( planeGeometry, planeMaterial );
this.scene.add(planeMesh);
```

this works as expected. Nothing out of the ordinary.

I include the [CSS3DRenderer.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/renderers/CSS3DRenderer.js) and add an iframe element.

The class contains a separate scene to hold HTML elements:

```
// create a new scene to hold CSS
this.cssScene = new THREE.Scene();
```

I create an element to use within the CSS scene:

```
//create the iframe to contain the html
var element = document.createElement('img');
element.src = "http://cdn.freshome.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/color-wheel.jpg";
var elementWidth = planeHeight;
//Use the planeMesh size
element.style.width  = planeWidth + "px";
element.style.height = planeHeight + "px";
//give it a z-index so we can place it behind our webGL canvas element
element.style.zIndex = "1";
```

I then create the CSS3DObject to place the element

```
var cssObject = new THREE.CSS3DObject( element );
```

position and rotation is matched to the planeMesh and added to the scene with render options:

```
cssObject.position = planeMesh.position;
cssObject.rotation = planeMesh.rotation;
this.cssScene.add(cssObject);
this.rendererCSS = new THREE.CSS3DRenderer();

this.rendererCSS.setSize( (window.innerWidth), window.innerHeight);
this.rendererCSS.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
this.rendererCSS.domElement.style.zIndex = 1;
this.rendererCSS.domElement.style.top = 0;
this.rendererCSS.domElement.style.left = 0;
this.rendererCSS.domElement.style.margin = 0;
this.rendererCSS.domElement.style.padding = 0;
this.container.appendChild(this.rendererCSS.domElement);
```

**The result**

In Firefox it's fine, Chrome it's not.

The size difference also affects panning of the camera, which causes the CSS3DObject to move away from the planeMesh in Chrome only. Firefox can pan both renderers, webGL and CSS, perfectly in sync.

Here is a screenshot showing the size discrepancy in Chrome, applying a wireframe to the planeMesh, you can see Chrome isn't filling the same space. I've worked out the discrepancy to be approximately 12-13% to small.

[image: Chrome and Firefox css 3d rendering difference]

**The Question:**
 Is there some unit of measurement I need to apply to Chrome to use for rendering 3d in the same space as webGL?

Comment: You code looks outdated. What version of three.js are you using? Is the Chrome webpage zoomed?

Comment: Uhg, it was scaled. Thanks! What part of the code appears out of date? I have been running threejs a long time and haven't had issues. I am using examples from the threejs website example set.

Comment: What revision of three.js are you using? It is posted in the Console output.

Comment: I'm on r.70. I will update to .71.

Comment: It may be helpful to know that some class level stuff that takes care of general mesh, topography, environment, fog, sun position, lighting, do not get updated frequently, but serve as boilerplate. I do update the library itself and fix any issues that crop up. The example above came from such a class, where i am adding the ability to add CSS3DObjects.

Comment: You code looks outdated because of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26905929/three-js-2xmeshes-using-same-vector-as-position/26916159#26916159).

Comment: I see now yes. It's not just syntax, it's literally a defect since copying the entire position object has no effect. I replaced the patterns with cssObject.position.set(planeMesh.position.x, planeMesh.position.y, planeMesh.position.z); and it's working.

Comment: Use `cssObject.position.copy( planeMesh.position );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `THREE.CSS3DRenderer`, and you are having scaling problems, make sure your webpage is not zoomed.

three.js r.71