# How to change a scale in three js (through assignment)

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have two object in threejs. And I would like them to share the value of `scale` vector

```
  mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material); 
  mesh1.scale.x = 0.47;

  mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material); 
  mesh2.scale=mesh1.scale;  // This does not work
```

The last line has no effect. The documentation does not state that the `scale` property is readonly. I've taken a look at the source and found that that property is not defined as writable. Is there a bug in documentation or is this the way threejs works and there is no point in documenting it :-) ?

Is it possible to share scale (and other vector) between different meshes? Is the only way to do it by copying the values

```
  mesh2.scale.copy(mesh1.scale);  // Copy the vector over
```

**UPDATE:** This seemed to work in old versions of threejs - such as the one used in the following example. Was this functionality disabled on purpose?

Comment: `scale` is vector so you need the copy constructor.

Comment: `Object3D.scale` is immutable. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26905929/three-js-2xmeshes-using-same-vector-as-position/26916159#26916159

Comment: @WestLangley Great answer- Now if you can add it as an answer (nto as comment) I can accept it :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Object3D`'s `position`, `rotation`, `quaternion` and `scale` properties are immutable.

See the source code file `Object3D.js`.

For example, you can no longer use the following pattern:

```
object.scale = vector;
```

Instead, you must use either

```
object.scale.set( x, y, z );
```

or

```
object.scale.copy( vector );
```

Similarly for the other properties mentioned.

three.js r.72