# OrbitControls.js Causes model to disappear when clicked to rotate

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm using OrbitControls.js to allow to user to zoom in / out and rotate 3D models displayed in my website. However, when i click anywhere on the page, the model disappears and the two buttons to switch between the models no longer works. Beforehand, it allows me to zoom in and out but not rotate.

Any help is greately appreciated.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <title>Visualising Cells</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="three.js"></script>
    <script src="ColladaLoader.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="OrbitControls.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>

    <div class="float-btn">
        <button type="button" id="LBC">Load Red Blood Cell</button>
        <button type="button" id="LEC">Load Egg Cell</button>
    </div>

    <div class="float-txt">
        <div style="color:#000000">
          <div style="font-family: Arial">
             <div style="font-size: 18px">
                 <div style="text-decoration: underline">
                     <h1>Visualising Microscopic Cells</h1>
                </div>

             <div class="instructions">
                 <div style="color:#000000">
                     <div style="font-family: Arial">
                         <div style="font-size: 16px">
                            <div style="text-decoration: underline">
                                 <h2>Instructions</h2>
                             </div>

             <div class="instruction-txt">
                <div style="color:#000000">
                    <div style="font-family: Arial">
                        <div style="font-size: 14px">
                            <p><u>Zoom In:</u> <strong>Up Arrow</strong> <br><u>Zoom Out:</u> <strong>Down Arrow</strong></br></p>
                        </div>

             <div class="Model-Location" id="target">
            </div>
</body>
</html>
```

.js

```
var myModel; // used to reference the most recently-loaded model

        $(document).ready(function() {
            // when the page has loaded, add click functions to the two buttons
            $("#LBC").click(function() {
                toggleModel("blood");
            });

            $("#LEC").click(function() {
                toggleModel("egg2");
            });
        });

        function toggleModel(modelName) {
            // remove the existing model from the scene
            scene.remove(myModel);
            // add the chosen model
            loadModel(modelName);
        }

        function loadModel(modelName) {
            // add the specified model
            loader.load(modelName+'.DAE', function (collada) {
                myModel = collada.scene;
                myModel.position.x = 0;
                myModel.position.y = 0;
                myModel.position.z = 0;
                myModel.updateMatrix();
                scene.add(myModel);                
            });
        }

        var width = window.innerWidth;
        var height = window.innerHeight;

        var scene = new THREE.Scene();

        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.01, 500 );
        camera.position.z = 0.16;
        camera.position.x = 0;
        camera.position.y = 0;
        scene.add(camera);

        var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );

        var renderer=new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize(width,height); 
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
        renderer.render(scene,camera);
        renderer.setClearColor("rgb(181,181,181)");

        light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
                light.position.set(1, 1, 1);
                scene.add(light);

        light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
                light.position.set(0, 0, 0.14);
                scene.add(light);

        var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();

        // load the default model
        loadModel("egg2");

                    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {        
            console.log(camera.position.z);
            if (event.keyCode == 38) {
                // don't scroll the window        
                console.log("Up Arrow Pressed");
                event.preventDefault();
                if (camera.position.z >= 0.1) {
                    camera.position.z = camera.position.z - 0.01;
                }

            }
            else if (event.keyCode == 40) {
                // don't scroll the window
                event.preventDefault();
                console.log("Down Arrow Pressed")

                if (camera.position.z < 0.2) {
                    camera.position.z = camera.position.z + 0.01;
                }

                }
            }, true);

        render = function () {
            requestAnimationFrame(render);

            // object.rotation.x += 0.0;
            // object.rotation.y += 0.0;

            renderer.render(scene, camera);            
            // controls.update();
        };

        controls.addEventListener('change', render );

        render();
```

Comment: Adding a fiddle would be a good idea.

Comment: @Wilt How do i do that?

Comment: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/wilt/mhxtdfp8/) is a starting point. You will have to make an account first, and then you can update this fiddle with your custom code and reproduce the issue that you are encountering. Then you add a link to the fiddle to your question so others can see for themselves what exactly your issue is about...

Comment: @Wilt It's not letting me make an account, it says a field if required when they are all filled in. All I need is the code to make a variable to add rotations to the models.

Answer (score 4):

I updated your fiddle and got it to work. Since you didn't include your collada models I used two models from three.js examples folder instead.

I have to say that your bug was very strange...

Here is a not working scene: https://jsfiddle.net/wilt/0c4mfo85/3/

Here is the working scene: https://jsfiddle.net/wilt/0c4mfo85/4/

The only difference between the working scene and the not working scene is the css declaration. I removed `position: fixed` from your canvas style. I Have no clue why this makes a difference...

```
canvas {
    position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Where abouts do i need to put the code within the file?

Comment: @Wilt Really? `object.rotation.x += 0.01;` is valid.

Comment: @WestLangley I thought in the newer three.js versions we have to avoid setting directly and rather use setters for these.

Comment: @G.Smith Sorry for the confusion. Just trying to help. Like I said before provide a fiddle and it will be much easier to help you find out what is wrong...

Comment: @Wilt http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26905929/three-js-2xmeshes-using-same-vector-as-position/26916159#26916159

Comment: @Wilt I've just tried making a fiddle but the models do not appear in the results box, even though the code is copied exactly from the editor I use. Here it is anyway https://jsfiddle.net/Greg_Smith14/0c4mfo85/

Comment: @G.Smith I will have a look at it tomorrow

Comment: @WestLangley makes sense... Thanks for the link.

Comment: @Wilt what do i need to change the path to within the colladaloader?

Comment: @G.Smith If you want to load your own models, you will need to change the `url` to the location of your own Collada models. Or is that not what you mean?

Comment: @Wilt ok so if the location of both the collada models is: This PC, Documents, A levels, EPQ, Website how do i write is as a url?

Comment: @Wilt it's saying the file is empty or non-existant.

Comment: @G.Smith You mean in the fiddle? You cannot load your local files in the fiddle. To load them you need to put them on some public spot (on the internet). Why are you not copying the code from the fiddle to your local project? Then you can continue working on it there. The fiddle was only to help me understand and find your issue and for you to see the solution...

Comment: @Wilt ive copied it to the my source code editor and when running the website everything apart from the models load, then in the console it says that the file is empty or non-existant.

Comment: @G.Smith did it ever load before? Check the url it is using. Did you remove what i added to the loader (`path + `). It seems this is a new issue and not related to the question you asked earlier...

Comment: @Wilt yes the model's loaded before. I've just removed the path + but the models still don't load.

Comment: @Wilt the code used to load the models previously is slightly different to the code you provided.

Comment: @Wilt Also, you cant simply just copy and paste the code from js fiddle as extra tags need to be added to the html file.

Comment: @G.Smith I spent a lot of time helping you and I managed to solve your issue and it is proven by the fiddles I provided. I suggest you accept my answer and carefully check what is wrong with your code right now. It must be something small that happened while copy pasting stuff around.

Comment: @I've just tried inserting my models into the code provided on your jsfiddle and that doesn't work either.

Comment: This is still a bug. In my case, it was `position: absolute` causing it, but all the same. My guess is that these kinds of positioning mess up the mouse events.