# How to animate and object along an elliptical path [Three.js]?

Tags: three.js

I am trying to move an Object3D group along a specific ellipse. I got it to move in a circle successfully using:

```
group.position.x = Math.cos(toRadians(loc+=5)) * radius;
group.position.z = Math.sin(toRadians(loc+=5)) * radius;
```

However, I want it to follow a specific 3 dimensional ellipse. I have the ellipse made successfully and visualized here:

```
curve = new THREE.EllipseCurve(0,0,80,60,0,toRad(360),false);
path = new THREE.Path( curve.getPoints( 2000 ) );
var geo = path.createPointsGeometry( 50 );

ellipse = new THREE.Line(
    geo,
    new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color : 0xff0000 } ) 
);
DISPLAY.scene.add(ellipse);
ellipse.rotation.x=toRadians(94);
ellipse.rotation.y=toRadians(12);
```

And I try to animate it like this (outside my 'render' function):

```
var pathAnim = new PathAnimation(group, path, 0.4);
```

Or even like this: (within the render function)

```
group.position=path.getPoint(t+=0.01); //i've tried getPoints, getPointAt, etc..
```

It doesn't seem to work. Any ideas as to how I can get this working? Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26905929/three-js-2xmeshes-using-same-vector-as-position/26916159#26916159.  Try `var v = path.getPoint( t ); mesh.position.set( v.x, v.y, 0 );` instead.

Comment: That did work, but any rotations I apply to the ellipse don't affect the animation path. Is there any way I could combine cubic bezier curves and have the group follow along the combined paths?

Comment: Probably... ---

Comment: I tried using CatmullRomCurve3 curves and had great success. The ellipses used with them look almost perfect whilst only needing to specify four Vector3 points and tweaking the '.tension' value. Thank you for your help; I used the code you supplied for getting/setting Vector3 values and it worked well with CatmullRomCurve3