# Javascript object property not updating on variable set

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am working with a Three.js Quaternion and I am having trouble saving my object's property for the Quaternion.

```
GLmol.prototype.initializeScene = function() {
   this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
   this.scene.fog = new THREE.Fog(this.bgColor, 100, 200);

   this.modelGroup = new THREE.Object3D();
   this.rotationGroup = new THREE.Object3D();
   this.rotationGroup.useQuaternion = true;

   this.rotationGroup.quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion(0.7235552851867599, -0.004228243257681183 , 0.004646778667168487, 0.6902378421133389);
   console.log(this.rotationGroup.quaternion)

   this.rotationGroup.add(this.modelGroup);

   this.scene.add(this.rotationGroup);
   this.setupLights(this.scene);
};
```

The problem I am getting is that when I set the this.rotationGroup.quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion(), it doesn't save the Quaternion object. When I look at the output I get

```
THREE.Quaternion (w:1 x:0 y:0 z:0)
```

Why do you think this is happening?

Comment: did you called the `initializeScene()` function?

Comment: Yes, It is called because I get the output from console.log(this.rotationGroup.quaternion), however its not the value that was set in the line right before.

Comment: Also, If I make a variable called, var test = new THREE.Quaternion(3, 3, 3, 3), and console.log(test) it works properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Object3D.quaternion` property is immutable, so this code is invalid:

```
rotationGroup.quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion( x, y, z, w );
```

Instead, use `.quaternion.copy( q )` or `.quaternion.set( x, y, z, w )`.

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26905929/three-js-2xmeshes-using-same-vector-as-position/26916159#26916159).

three.js r.84

Comment: Thank you, I used set and everything works properly. I am modifying code and they tried the way I did, however, it was actually set earlier in code and the line I was copying did nothing. Thank you.