# Converting rotation stored as a quaternion to an Euler for a three.js mesh

Tags: three.js

A dataset I am trying to import into a three.js scene (r92) stores the rotation of each component as a quaternion. I am trying to convert each to an Euler that I can apply as a rotation and currently using this:

```
mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

var q0 = -0.26621186733245849609375;  
var q1 = 0.1366209685802459716796875;    
var q2 = -0.849540293216705322265625;    
var q3 = 0.817855589389801025390625;
var quat = new THREE.Quaternion(q0, q1, q2, q3);
var rotation = new THREE.Euler().setFromQuaternion(quat, "XYZ");
mesh.rotation.x = rotation.x;
mesh.rotation.y = rotation.y;
mesh.rotation.z = rotation.z;
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/96Luzm1n/

Based on visual inspection, the rotations are incorrect and I've tried altering the XYZ order to every possible combination - what am I doing wrong?

Edit:  Answer from comments is to set the quaternion directly using code like this: https://jsfiddle.net/zeoncgo0/

Comment: Mmm... why don't you set rotation directly as quaternion? `mesh.quaternion = ...` ?

Comment: Hmm.. I didn't know about that and certainly makes sense. However, adding `mesh.quaternion = quat` doesn't affect the rotation at all. 
https://jsfiddle.net/kc8s18bv/

What did I miss?

Comment: `mesh.quaternion.set( x, y, z, w );` -- and make sure you get the arguments in the correct order.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26905929/three-js-2xmeshes-using-same-vector-as-position/26916159#26916159

Comment: Yep, just figured that out - rotation is still wrong though compared to what I see in the app where the objects are created.  There are no docs so I assumed `rotation = (4 floats)` was a quaternion - at least I know my code is correct.

Comment: Good, you figured it out. Learned something as well - position, rotation and quaternion now are immutable

Comment: @speedwell Different math libs sometimes have different ordering of quaternion elements.. sometimes you have to swap elements, like wxyz or something. One way to check is to take a known rotation in both apps.. like say.. 45 degrees on the y axis, then compare the resulting quat from both three, and your external app and verify that the numbers are similar/in the right positions.

Comment: @ manthrax yep that was my next thing to try.  Sadly, adding an ID to the object in original app so I can find it in my JS code and inspect the rotation moves it to a location in the data file that my simple parser doesn't see.  Lots of things to try though - thanks all.

Comment: I was able to tag an object in the original app, capture it's XYZ rotation in degrees. When I set the quaternion on the JS side, display the `rotation` values converted to degrees, they match so I think the code is correct as far as it goes but I'm missing something else.